# How to fix "No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'" in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin to create a small Android app, and I run into this problem when trying to add a splash screen to my app. I have the same problem wether I'm building my own project or the official Xamarin example on how to implement splash screens.

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Is the `v7 AppCompat` library installed? Have you tried clearing the `bin/obj` folders and rebuilding?